# Azure Function with Azure AD Authentication - Allowed Token Audiences not work for Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have configured Azure Function with Azure AD auth, follow this doc - [Enable Azure Active Directory in your App Service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app).

After the configuration, it will add the function app url e.g. `https://appname.azurewebsites.net` to the `Allowed Token Audiences` like below automatically, then we can easily use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token to call the e.g. http trigger in my function app.

[image]

If I add the Azure AD Graph resource url `https://graph.windows.net` to the `Allowed Token Audiences`, I can also use this flow to get the token to call my function.

[image]

[image]

But if I add the Microsoft Graph resource url `https://graph.microsoft.com` and get the token to call the function, I will get the error.

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

[image]

[image]

How to solve this issue? Is this correct usage of `Allowed Token Audiences`? If not, why the `https://graph.windows.net` work fine?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @GovindSharma-MSFTIdentity I don't think they answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check in your app registration in azure AD under api permissions if Microsoft graph has been added ? If not please add it as a delegated permission and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is the trick. Delegated permission will not take effect in client credential flow. There is no permission in the API permissions of my client app even the AAD Graph, but it works for AAD Graph(`https://graph.windows.net`).

Comment: Thanks for the response I am able to reproduce this seems like we get 401 only for Microsoft graph as a scope tried azure storage as a scope it returns 200.

Comment: Thanks for your test, if so, it is so weird, I just want to know why it does not work for Microsoft graph.

Comment: If you have an app service which is on a basic or above tier you can turn on authentication /authorization  on it and perform a call to the website by passing token with graph as a scope you will be able to reproduce this issue.You can turn on the application insight which will help us track all the failed request this should probably giv e us more information on the error.I have an app service and i am able to reproduce the issue but since the tier is free profiler is disabled and doesn't track the failed request.

Comment: Additionally if application insights is enabled on your functions app you can scout through the logs to check for failed requests.

Comment: Tried app insight, but looks the logs will not enter it, seems the auth is above the function and will not be recognized as failed.

Comment: I was to able track the failed request logs but unfortunately the easy_auth module in the logs doesn't give any information whatsoever.The only option left is to take up this issue with the Azure AD/MSFT-Identity team lets see what explanation they come up with .I have tried acquiring the token through all the 3 flows (client cred/Implicit grant/Auth code) with graph as scope but none of them succeeded.

Comment: Technically azure function should not allow graph.windows.net to validate the Microsoft graph token however could you please share the valid reasons why you are implementing this way and please share request URL and token information

Answer (score 0):

According to the document you need to provide Application ID URI in Allowed Token Audiences. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app)

**If this is a cloud or server app and you want to allow authentication tokens from a web app, add the Application ID URI of the web app here. The configured Client ID is always implicitly considered to be an allowed audience.**

[image]

Comment: Hi ..sorry for the late response ..I agree completely that the allowed audience of the function app should be set as app id uri of the function app...but we observed an anomaly here that with allowed audience set to graph.windows.net and if we acquire a token whose intended audience is graph.windows.net the request to function app succeeds where as if the audience is graph.windows.com the request fails with a 401.